# Twitter.com - How is the login screen background image rendered?

Tags: html

On the twitter.com login screen, there is a background which features a world map behind the text.

I've had a look and I'm not sure how it's being rendered. I found this one background image (http://a2.twimg.com/a/1316626057/phoenix/img/front/bg.png) which looks more like the color behind the globe overlay.

Any ideas how the map part is being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is part of the [logo image](http://a2.twimg.com/a/1316626057/phoenix/img/front/logo-map.png), which is `#doc`’s background image.

Comment: Cheers - I didn't see it because it's white :)

Answer (score 1):

The div that takes up the whole page (`<div id='doc'>`) has this style set on it:

```
background: url("../img/front/logo-map.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent
```

This makes that image the background of the div, and therefore the page.

Answer (score 0):

That picture is not the world! that is just the body's background picture. The world, is background of this div:

```
<div class="route-front" id="doc">
```

and is in this folder:

```
../img/front/logo-map.png
```

related with this stylesheet file:

```
http://a2.twimg.com/a/1316626057/phoenix/css/phoenix_core_logged_out.bundle.css
```